# compilation error when passing null as constructor/method argument - c#

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

Today when i want to verify an object is instantiated correctly with an injected argument, I do something like this:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    private object _someArgument;

    public SomeObject(object someArgument)
    {
        if (someArgument == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someArgument");
        }

        this._someArgument = someArgument;
    }
}
```

But I was wandering if I can catch such issues at compile time to avoid errors in run time.

E.g.

```
// Get a compilation error since null was passed
var someInstance = new SomeObject(null);
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: No, I don't think that its possible.

Comment: we use resharper annotations to achive this https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly that's interesting, it will require however all developers to have resharper installed right?

Comment: @Y.S yes, reshaper is required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Code Contracts](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970). It does not produce compile time errors. However it performs static checking on your code and gives warnings if it detects code like `var someInstance = new SomeObject(null);`

You can use it like this:

```
public SomeObject(object someArgument)
{
    Contract.Requires(someArgument != null);

    this._someArgument = someArgument;
}
```

Comment: I was going to post this answer, but since you already did, I'll just add that there's no need to change the code at all due to "*Legacy Requires Statements*".

Comment: @Amit can you explain? what do you mean by no need to change the code?

Comment: @Y.S - look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx), pay attention to *Legacy Requires Statements*".

Comment: Well this seems like a good answer, if no other answer shows up here that does allow compilation errors in a better way I will accept it.